# How to create SQL queries using an SHA-1 digest of a string using Python

Tags: java, python, mysql, sql, sha1

I'm trying to insert hundreds of accounts into a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database. I can't insert clear-text passwords and my application is expecting an [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash for passwords. A quick online search pointed me to [Python's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) hashlib libray.

Here's my Python code to generate a SHA-1 hash:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha1();
m.update("kpVtk5y6");
m.digest();
```

How can I use m.digest in the SQL query to store passwords?

My web application uses Java's MessageDigest.digest(mypassword.getBytes()) method to store passwords, so I need to implement something similar in Python in order to auto inject user accounts.

Comment: Instead of using m.digest(), could you use m.hexdigest() instead? That way, you're working with ASCII strings instead of binary.

Comment: Actually, I don't have to work with ASCII strings and the password field is defined as byte[] not a String. Does python have a byte[] equivalent? Java's MessageDigest.digest() returns a byte[] and I need exactly that in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put semicolons on the end of lines in Python.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5241478/181772 what you say you are doing should work. For example:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost')
r = conn.cursor()
r.execute('INSERT INTO users (hash) VALUES (%s)', m.digest())
conn.commit()
```

Because `m.digest()` is returning a `str` which is Python 2's equivalent of bytes. And the link above shows that those can be inserted into the MySQL database.

So if that's what you are already doing, it sounds like you have a mistake in your code.