# Inserting bytes object into a database using Python

Tags: python, sql, blob

What is the best way to insert a raw bytes object into a SQL database using Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241031/python-inserting-and-retrieving-binary-data-into-mysql?rq=1

Comment: I don't think so because I don't want to use uuid (I don't need a key)

Comment: what about pack/unpack in python and use int/hex in db?